# Attaching a File to Multiple Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

How can you *beautifully* attach the same file to multiple ActiveRecord objects?

```
object1.image.attach(params[:image])
blob = object1.image.blob
object2.image.attach(blob)
object3.image.attach(blob)
object4.image.attach(blob)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not necessarily *beautiful*, it does get the job done with a minimal amount of code:

```
blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload!(io: file, filename: filename)
objects.each do |object|
  object.image.attach(blob)
end
```

But it would be great if we had a simple rails method something like this:

```
MyClass.image.attach(objects, params[:image])
```